# Trigger Azure Functions on Databricks changes

Tags: azure-functions, azure-databricks

Is it possible to trigger Azure functions as soon as data in the Databricks Table is loaded? Ultimately once the data in databricks table is available (via python scripts), I need to trigger external API of the middleware to take extract the data.

Thank you.

Viren

Couldnt find any solution yet

Answer (score 0):

There is Azure [Databricks REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/) that does lot of tasks programmatically and target changes are also observed.

> Is it possible to trigger Azure functions as soon as data in the Databricks Table is loaded?

It is possible with the Serverless Architecture which is combination of Logic Apps & Azure Functions.

As @*MikeUrnun* suggested an [cdata article](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/databricks-odata-azure-logic-app.rst) that uses the Logic Apps Recurrence trigger for polling for the changes in Databricks and deliver the data/information to the associated Function app.

[image]

[image]

You need to Authenticate the REST API using either AAD Tokens or PATs.
After Configuring the Databricks REST API Login > Authentication with certain Token and Authorization > Configure the Next action to Azure Function App for the functionality based on your requirement

If Azure Functions is the only resource you need to use for achieving the requirement, then you can create Timer Trigger and invoke the Azure Databricks REST API using `HttpClient` programmatically and can write the code for passing the extracted data to a database or storage account.